How to static link dependency in meson build?
I am trying to static link a dependency in the meson build but I am getting this error:
WARNING: Static library 'sndfile' not found for dependency 'sndfile', may not be statically linked
WARNING: Static library 'mpg123' not found for dependency 'sndfile', may not be statically linked

I tried to pass the static: true to the dependency in the meson.build file:
sndfile_dep = dependency('sndfile', version: '>= 1.0.16', required: get_option('cmdline'), static: true)

But I am getting the above error.
Secondly, I cloned to libsndfile library and tried to build it statically by following:
./configure --enable-static
make
sudo make install

And adding that to the meson.build file:
  sndfile_dep = cpp.find_library('sndfile',
                                 dirs: get_option('extra_lib_dirs'),
                                 has_headers: ['sndfile.h'],
                                 header_args: extra_include_args,
                                 required: get_option('cmdline'),
                                 static: true)

The build is successful but its not statically linked when checked by ldd:
libsndfile.so.1 => /usr/local/lib/libsndfile.so.1 (0x00007f4d3b6a9000)

UPDATE:
I statically linked the libraries by setting:
sndfile_dep = dependency('sndfile', version: '>= 1.0.16', required: get_option('cmdline'), static: true)

And installing:
sudo apt-get install libsndfile-dev
sudo apt-get install libmpg123-dev

And now I am getting this error on AWS Lambda:
"rubberband: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by rubberband)",
"rubberband: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by rubberband)",
"rubberband: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by rubberband)",
"rubberband: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by rubberband)",
"rubberband: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by rubberband)",
"rubberband: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by rubberband)",

